# Integrate singular kernels - Hankel functions

Tags: boundary-value-problem, bessel-functions

I am working on a 2D Boundary Integral Method code for acoustics problems and I need to integrate singular kernels.

The functions that I have to deal with are:

$$
I_{1} = \int_{-1}^{1} H_0 ^{(1)}(r)dr
$$
$$
I_{2} = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dH_0 ^{(1)}(r)}{dr}\frac{1}{r} dr
$$

Is there any idea of how can I do that? I though about evaluating it using small argument approximations, but I can't find it anywhere.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Antiderivative  for  $I_1$  can be found at [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22.E2). For $I_2$, one can use the same expression by taking $\nu=-1$ and remarking that $d/dr [H_0^{(1)}(r)]=-H_1^{(1)}(r)=H_{-1}^{(1)}(r)$.

Comment: In what way do you have ${H_0}^{(1)}(r)$ expressed?